# LVS LocalNode not working on Kernel 4.1.6

Tags: linux, high-availability

I am try to following LVS document to setup LVS as a LocalNode.

http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.localnode.html

```
$ sudo ipvsadm -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size = 4096)
Prot LocalAddress: Port Scheduler Flags
   -> RemoteAddress: Port Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP 172.20.10.5:8090 rr
   -> 127.0.0.1:8090 Route 1 0 0
```

but it is not recognized as LocalNode.

Does LocalNode features or would have been removed in recent lvs built into the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find the answer from japan stackoverflow commmunity.

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16650/lvs-localnode-%E3%81%86%E3%81%BE%E3%81%8F%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C